# Pandas to multiple the value of a column that satisfies greater and less than condition

Tags: python, pandas

How to use pandas to multiple the value of columns that satisfies greater and less than condition?

```
df['res'] = ((df['value']<=3) & (df['value']>=1)) * 1.5 *df['value']

df['res'] = ((df['value']<=7) & (df['value']>=4)) * 1.3 *df['value']
```

This above is what i've tried. However, i kept getting the message:

> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead"

And the 'res' goes to 0 when i try to have more than 2 conditions.

Below is what i hope to achieve:

```
value    res
2        3
6        7.8
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing two kind of objects: masks, that are boolean series, and the original column of the dataframe that is a series with numeric values.
This should do the trick:

```
mask1 = (df['value']<=3) & (df['value']>=1)
mask2 = (df['value']<=7) & (df['value']>=4)
df.loc[mask1, 'res'] = df['value'] * 1.5
df.loc[mask2, 'res'] = df['value'] * 1.3
print(df)
```

```
   value  res
0      2  3.0
2      6  7.8
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get a range using this:

`df['res'] = df['value'].between(1, 3, inclusive=True)`

Here inclusive decides whether endpoints should be included or not.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use the `.between` method to create such mask, namely:

```py
df.loc[df['value'].between(1,3), 'res'] = df[ df['value'].between(1,3), 'value'] * 1.5
df.loc[df['value'].between(4,7), 'res'] = df[ df['value'].between(4,7), 'value'] * 1.3
```

alternatively, you can also use the `np.where` function, which act as a if-else:

```py
df['res'] = np.where(df['value'].between(1,3), 
                     df['value'] * 1.5,
                     np.where(df['value'].between(4,7),
                              df['value'] * 1.3,
                              df['value']))
```